# Is there a way to assign aliases easily? E.g. SUM(deposit_amount) as deposit_amount

Tags: sql, oracle, alias, naming, impala

I often do queries where I do a lot of SUM, COUNT and even NVL(). Most of the time I end up calling the calculated value the same as before.

So for example currently I have this in my code:

```
    sum(vl.margin_1d) as margin_1d,
    sum(vl.margin_7d) as margin_7d,
    sum(vl.margin_14d) as margin_14d,
    sum(vl.margin_28d) as 
    sum(vl.margin_35d) as 
    sum(vl.margin_42d) as 
    sum(vl.margin_56d) as 

    sum(vl.deposit_1d) as 
    sum(vl.deposit_7d) as 
    sum(vl.deposit_14d) as 
    sum(vl.deposit_28d) as 
    sum(vl.deposit_35d) as 
    sum(vl.deposit_42d) as 
    sum(vl.deposit_56d) as
```

I have loads more calculated values like this and so it takes a lot of time (and it's pretty boring too) to type down the same aliases after each sum.

Is there maybe some trick to do this more easily?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
SUM(deposit_7d) as SAME
```

Thanks,
Sophie

P.S. This piece of code in particular is in impala, but I also use Oracle frequently.

Comment: `SUM(deposit_7d)` is not the same as `deposit_7d`, that's why you need explicit alias.

Answer (score 2):

If all you're wanting to do is avoid some typing, you could knock up a query to do the work for you, e.g. in Oracle, I'd do something like:

```
select 'sum(vl.'||column_name||') as '||column_name||','
from   all_tab_columns
where  table_name = 'YOUR_TABLENAME'
and    column_name in (...)
order by column_name;
```

Or you could use Excel and its CONCATENATE() formula to take a list of column names and output the data you want for each column name, or if you have a text editor that supports regular expressions you could do similar.